# Seasborn Distplot goes unresponsive

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a simple `Distplot` using `pandas` and `seaborn` to understand the density of the datasets.

Input

```
#Car,45
#photo,4
#movie,6
#life,1
#Horse,14
#Pets,20
#run,67
#picture,89
```

The dataset has above `10K` rows, `no headers` and I am trying to use `col[1]`

code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns


df = pd.read_csv('keyword.csv', delimiter=',', header=None, usecols=[1])
#print df
sns.distplot(df)

plt.show()
```

No error as I can print the input column but the `distplot` is taking ages to compute and freezes my screen. Any suggestion to speed the process.

**Edit1:** As Suggested in the Comment Below I try to change from `pandas.read_csv` to `np.loadtxt` and now I get an error.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import log as log
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas

df = np.loadtxt('keyword.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(1), unpack=True)
sns.kdeplot(df)
sns.distplot(df)

plt.show()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "0_distplot_csv.py", line 7, in <module>
    df = np.loadtxt('keyword.csv', delimiter=',', usecols=(1), unpack=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 726, in loadtxt
    usecols = list(usecols)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

**Edit 2:** I did try the mentioned suggestions from the comment section

```
sns.distplot(df[1])
```

This does the same as mentioned initially. The screen is frozen for ages.

```
sns.distplot(df[1].values)
```

I see a strange behavior in this case.

When the input is

```
Car,45
photo,4
movie,6
life,1
Horse,14
Pets,20
run,67
picture,89
```

It does plot but when the input is below

```
#Car,45
#photo,4
#movie,6
#life,1
#Horse,14
#Pets,20
#run,67
#picture,89
```

It is again the same freezing entire screen and would do nothing.

I did try to put `comments=None` thinking it might be reading them as comments. But looks like `comments` isn't used in `pandas`.

Thank you

Comment: You need to make a minimum working example that reproduces the problem. If the four lines of data is really the full extent of your file, use `io.StringIO` to include it in your script.

Comment: The code works when I specify column header but I do not have headers I need to use column no. And the data is four lines from the original dataset.  It is not continues in nature.

Comment: Try just passing an array then

Comment: you can still read the file with pandas, just convert the column you need to a series or an array. e.g. `seaborn.distplot(df[0])` or `seaborn.distplot(df[0].values)`

Comment: Thank you will try this.

Comment: @PaulH I did try your suggestions and they show a little strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several trials and a lot of online search, I could finally get what I was looking for. The code allows to load data with column number when we do not have headers. This also reads the rows with `#` comments.

code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
from scipy.stats.kde import gaussian_kde
import seaborn as sns

data = np.genfromtxt('keyword.csv', delimiter=',', comments=None)

d0=data[:,1]

#Plot a simple histogram with binsize determined automatically
sns.kdeplot(np.array(d0), color='b', bw=0.5, marker='o', label='keyword')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Freq(x)')
plt.ylabel('pdf(x)')
#plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
#plt.gca().set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```