# IndexError: too many indices for array Numpy Plotting CCDF with CSV

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, cdf

I am trying to plot a `CCDF` using `numpy` and input is `csv` with `#keywords` as `col[0]` and frequency as `col[1]`.

Input

```
#Car,45
#photo,4
#movie,6
#life,1
```

Input has more than 10K rows and two column out of which `col[0]` is not used at all and only the frequency from `col[1]` is used to plot the `CCDF`. The data has no empty rows in-between nor eof has any blank row.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import*
import math
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator

data = np.genfromtxt('input.csv', delimiter=",")

d0=data[:,1]
X0 = np.sort(d0)
cdf0 = np.arange(len(X0))/float(len(X0))
#cumulative = np.cumsum(data)
ccdf0 = 1 - cdf0
plt.plot(X0,ccdf0, color='b', marker='.', label='Frequency')

plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlabel('Freq (x)')
plt.ylabel('ccdf(x)')
plt.gca().set_xscale("log")
#plt.gca().set_yscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "00_plot_ccdf.py", line 17, in <module>
    d0=data[:,1]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`genfromtxt` by default treats lines starting with `#` as comments, so actually your `data` is empty:

```
In [1]: genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',')         
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py:1385: UserWarning: genfromtxt: Empty input file: "test.csv"
  warnings.warn('genfromtxt: Empty input file: "%s"' % fname)
Out[1]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`data` is a 1-dimensional empty array and so `[:,1]` is too many indices.

To disable this pass `comments=None` to `genfromtxt`:

```
In [20]: genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', comments=None)
Out[20]: 
array([[ nan,  45.],
       [ nan,   4.],
       [ nan,   6.],
       [ nan,   1.]])
```

Since you need only the 2. column, you can also limit the results to that directly:

```
In [21]: genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=',', comments=None, usecols=(1,))
Out[21]: array([ 45.,   4.,   6.,   1.])
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. Let me try this and will reply back .. Thanks again ! :)

Comment: Works like a charms.. Thank you so much .. been searching a lot. And may be I could use a little suggestion on this one too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616118/seasborn-distplot-goes-unresponsive

Comment: @SitzBlogz ipython has a nice feature: type a question mark after a class, function etc. and enter (`genfromtxt?` for example), and it'll display helpful information. This is especially nice for numpy, scipy etc. stuff, as it prints a very matlab like help text.